# Freeform notification email to zoo visitor member's email address too

Tags: solspace

client would like to send notification not only to enquirer (ie email submitted in form) but also the Zoo Visitor member they enquired about 'title' gets passed to a field on the form so populates form automatically – but would somehow need to get the Zoo Visitor Member's email and use that in the notification too!

Its a music agency website and the Zoo Visitors are bands – the enquirer would be a person enquiring about the band, any ideas!?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of where you're getting the email address from, could likely accomplish the notification by feeding that email address into a parameter such as [admin_notify](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#admin_notify):

```
admin_notify="{email}"
```

Or directly into the [recipient_email_user](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#recipient_email_user) field:

```
<input type="text" name="recipient_email_user" value="{email}" />
```